# PHP change file name on upload for thumbnails

Tags: php, file-upload, file-rename

I am adding "_thumb" to the file name if the radio button "thumbnail" is selected, and don't add it (leave the file name as it is) if "full size" is selected. This works for my database entries, but not for the actual file. I suspect that I somehow add "_thumb" to both types of files - thumbnail and fullsize - because in the folder where I upload to I only see the one with "_thumb" added. I can't figure out what's wrong, help please!

This is my php so far:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
$_SESSION['category']=$_POST['category']; }
if(isset($_POST['size'])) {
$_SESSION['size']=$_POST['size']; }
?>
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Upload</title>
<style>.thumbnails{height:60px;display:block;}.galery{height:200px;}</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Melvin","") or die ("could not connect to server: " . mysqli_connect_error($con));
mysqli_select_db($con, "galerie") or die ("Could not connect to database: " . mysqli_error($con));

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$location = '_images/_galerie/';
$target = '_images/_galerie/' .$name;

 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name)){
  
  echo "Successfully uploaded";
  
  $nam = $_POST['nam'];
  $category = $_POST['category'];
  $size = $_POST['size'];
  
  if ($size == 'thumb') {
   // add "thumb" between filename and extension    
   $extension_pos = strrpos($target, '.'); // find position of the last dot, so where the extension starts
   $thumb = substr($target, 0, $extension_pos) . '_thumb' . substr($target, $extension_pos);   
   $query = mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO images(img_name,img_title,img_cat,img_size)VALUES('".$thumb."','$nam','$category','$size')"); 
  } else {
   $query = mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO images(img_name,img_title,img_cat,img_size)VALUES('".$target."','$nam','$category','$size')"); 
  }  
  
  function renameImg() {
   $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $target = '_images/_galerie/' .$name;
   $extension_pos = strrpos($target, '.');
   $thumb = substr($target, 0, $extension_pos) . '_thumb' . substr($target, $extension_pos);
   rename($target, $thumb);
   //echo $name . " replaced with " . $thumb;
  };
  renameImg();
  
 } else {
  
  echo "file not uploaded";
   
 }

}
?>

<div style="margin:20px 0 40px 0;">
    <form action="stack_overflow_upload_2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
        Upload: <input type="file" name="file">
        Title: <input type="text" name="nam" value="Image Gallery">
        Category: <select name="category" id="selectCat">
   
            <option value="black" 
   <?php 
   if (isset($_SESSION['category'])) {
    if($_SESSION['category'] == "black"){ 
     echo ' selected'; }}
   ?> >black</option>
            <option value="colour" 
   <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['category'])) {
    if($_SESSION['category'] == "colour"){ 
     echo ' selected'; }}
   ?> >colour</option>
        </select>
        
         <br>           
         
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="full" id="regularRadio"        
        <?php
         if(isset($_SESSION['size'])) {
    if($_SESSION['size'] == "full") {
     echo 'checked="checked" ';
    }
   }
  ?> >
        <label for="regularRadio">Full size</label>
        <br>         
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="thumb" id="thumbRadio"
        <?php
         if(isset($_SESSION['size'])) {
    if($_SESSION['size'] == "thumb") {
     echo 'checked="checked" ';
    }
   }
  ?> >
        <label for="thumbRadio">Thumbnail</label>
        <br>
        
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE img_size='thumb'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
 echo "<img src=".$row['img_name'] . " &nbsp; class='thumbnails' style='display:inline;float:left;'>";
  
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `renameImage()` is a lot of extra work when you could just be using [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo).

Comment: thanks for your reply! how would i apply that? i'm sorry, i'm still a beginner with PHP...

Comment: `$f  = pathinfo($_FILES[blahblah]); $newname = $f['basename'] . '_thumb' . $f['extension'];`

Comment: after i changed 'basename' to 'filename' this worked... if you put it as an answer i can mark it as the correct one... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just add this way on your renameImg function

```
if(file_exists('_images/_galerie/' .$name))
    rename('_images/_galerie/' .$name, $thumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check the file uploaded in uploads folder as follows:
if(file_exists('path/'.$file_name){
 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name)){
 // file need to be upload in the uploads folder then upload the file into inner folder or may be same folder
 $thumb_image=$name.'_thumb';
if(copy(source,destination)){
 echo 'file uploaded successfully';
 // you can delete the file uploaded in the uploads folder as the file is uploaded in the inner folderes
}
}
}
```